# Draw circles using for-loop Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, loops, for-loop

I want to draw 7 circles using Qt in C++

I want to use a for loop;
However, I am unable to, I actually wanted to used the width of the window to equally space my circles which is not working out as well. Where am I wrong. I am new to programming. :)

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6;i++)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = (width()/6);
    x =y+x;
    canvas.drawEllipse(x, 40, 20, 20);
}
```

Okay I was working on it and now I have five circles with this code

```
     int x = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i <= 6;i++)
   {

    x = x+(width()/6);
    canvas.drawEllipse(x, 40, 20, 20);
    }
```

But I want the first circle to start at 
      canvas.drawEllipse(0, 40, 20, 20);

In addition how can I change the color of one circle if I am switching from one page to another. Its an application with about 7 pages and each circle would represent a page so for example if I am on page 1 circle 1 should be green.
I have been told to create a function for this but how do I go about it referencing my pages and the circles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some math here.

Let Screen_Width be the width of the screen, in pixels.
Let Screen_Height be the height of the screen, in pixels.

The width of an ideal circle is the same as the diameter, or 2 * radius.
However, this is reality, sow we have to account for line widths.
So the actual width of a circle is: `Diameter + 2 * Circle_Line_Width`;

Also, this being reality and not ideal conditions, we would like spacing between the circles.
Let Spacing be the distance, in pixels between the outer lines of the circles.

Let Circle_Quantity be the number of circles.

So, the total width occupied by the circle is:

```
Circle_Width = Diameter + 2 * Circle_Line_Width + (Space_Between_Circles / 2);
```

The space available for a circle (with spacing) is:

```
Available_Circle_Space = Screen_Width / Circle_Quantity;
```

Now comes the trick, locating the centers of the circles.
Let's find out the values of the circle properties.
Solving for the diameter:

```
Diameter = Circle_Width / (2 * Circle_Line_Width + (Space_Between_Circles/2));
```

Remember, the center of the circle will be the midpoint of the diameter, which is `Diameter / 2`.

So, the first center point is:

```
  0 /*Left edge ordinate */
  + (Space_Between_Circles/2)
  + Circle_Line_Width
  + (Diameter / 2)
```

The next center point is at:

```
Previous_Center_Point
  + (Space_Between_Circles/2)
  + Circle_Line_Width
  + (Diameter / 2)
```

This should show you how to make a `for` loop to draw all the circles.

Answer (score 0):

Switch around the two statements in the loop:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 6;i++)
{
    canvas.drawEllipse(x, 40, 20, 20); //0 on 1st iteration
    x = x+(width()/6); //x = 0 + (width()/6), which will be used on 2nd iteration, etc.
}
```

To use `x` as 0 in the first loop, you save adding `width()/6` until after you've first used it.